# Groupby one column then sum up another value column and count rows then calculate percentage for each in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:8, type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), values = c(360000L, 
331715L, 260000L, 164900L, NA, 120000L, 331238L, 629861L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

[image]

How could I groupby `type` and sum up `values` and count numbers of entries, then calculate `value_percent` and `number_percent` for each `type`?

The expected result will like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help at advance.

**Update:**

`value_percent` become all `1`s if Chinese characters inside dataset for @Karthik S's solution.

```
df <- structure(list(物业类型 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("商业/零售", "数据中心", 
"写字楼", "综合体"), class = "factor"), 成交总价.万元. = c(360000L, 
331715L, 260000L, 164900L, NA, 120000L, 331238L, 629861L, 68800L, 
47600L, 804600L, 450000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(物业类型) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(总额占比 = sum(成交总价.万元., na.rm = T)/sum(成交总价.万元., na.rm = T), 笔数占比 = n()/nrow(df))
```

Out:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(value_percent = sum(values, na.rm = TRUE),
            count_percent = n()) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('percent'), prop.table))

#  type  value_percent count_percent
#  <fct>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#1 a            0.433          0.375
#2 b            0.0750         0.25 
#3 c            0.492          0.375
```

Comment: It works after I use `detach(package:plyr)`. Many thanks.

Comment: I test with new data, `prop.table` function seems not working when the values are `int`?

Comment: I don't think so `prop.table(1L:10L)` works fine.

Comment: I get it, I need to pass column names to `prop.table`, with `df %>% dplyr::group_by(type) %>% dplyr::summarise(count = n()) %>% arrange(desc(count)) %>% mutate(per = prop.table(count))`, it works.

Comment: But it seems not equivalent to @Karthik S's solution, which is `df %>% dplyr::group_by(type) %>% dplyr::summarise(per = n()/nrow(df)) %>%  arrange(desc(per))`.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
> df %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise(value_percent = sum(values,na.rm = T)/sum(df$values, na.rm = T), count_percent = n()/nrow(df))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  type  value_percent count_percent
  <fct>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 a            0.433          0.375
2 b            0.0750         0.25 
3 c            0.492          0.375
>
```

Comment: I tested your method with my real data, all the `value_percent` become `1`, I don't know why. It works for the data in the question, maybe because of `NaN`s?

Comment: No if there's a NaN, na.rm will work on that. For ex: > sum(c(1,2,NaN))
[1] NaN
> sum(c(1,2,NaN), na.rm = T)
[1] 3
>

Comment: It seems this only happens if data has chinese characters inside, I'll update the data and my code for you to test.